# Link only flag got declined for answer: "Here is a rather descriptive starting point."

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756932/progress-bar-in-winforms/756943#756943) back in September (used Other with *link only answer* as description), and recently it got declined with the following note:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

It says this answer is not link-only and my flag didn't count as helpful flags. But it actually is, as there is a new comment added to the answer basically saying this is current a link-only answer and asking for improvement? So shouldn't my flag still be treated as accepted?

The answer is as follows (full quote):

> [Here is a rather descriptive starting point.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jieying/UsingProgressBarStatusBarandTimerControlsinVS.NET11282005021220AM/UsingProgressBarStatusBarandTimerControlsinVS.NET.aspx)

Comment: [I'd read this recent meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272982/do-moderators-want-link-only-answer-flags-or-not)

Comment: So, just for the record, what flag type did you use?

Comment: @gunr2171 It was an "Other" flag - only for moderators with the very helpful description _link only answer_.

Comment: @bluefeet, as you said the description is very helpful, why did you decline it?... (just kidding) I get the idea, so next time I should use other flags like NAA? I was thinking all the flags goes to moderators anyway..

Comment: just run an experiment with flagging this answer. Looks funny how moderator handling it has chosen to ignore the guidance from Community Manager I quoted right there, in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756932/progress-bar-in-winforms/756943#comment41236864_756943) posted under the answer: "Moderators, if you see it flagged, _delete it_..."

Comment: @gnat I'm not a mod so I can't really say whether this played a part, but perhaps this is along the lines of [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402) (the answer is from 2009).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot since this is not about closing, it looks more likely that this is along the lines of moderators being ["conditioned for years to act opposite"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273142/link-only-flag-got-declined-for-answer-here-is-a-rather-descriptive-starting-p?noredirect=1#comment103248_273143) (opposite to guidance I quoted)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I think that should only be applied to questions?

Comment: @Bolu I said "along the lines of." In general, moderation is more lax with old content. There are many posts on meta asking "why is this question/answer allowed on the site contrary to site guidelines" and the answer is invariably, "because it's old. The rules were different back then."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yeah, find it more than once, moderators will judge differently on old/voted questions/answers/comments.

Comment: FWIW the answer is gone now (last time I checked it dropped to -5)

Answer (score 17):

You are correct about the answer being a link-only answer: there is just a link and nothing more. Posting link-only answers is against SO policies so the answer should get deleted.

The correct action is to flag such posts. You can down vote and comment but it isn't necessary.

However, link-only answer problems can be handled by the community, you don't need to use the "other" flag. When you do, you ring the bell for the diamond moderators, something that you should reserve for more serious concerns.

I've done the very same thing myself: "This is a link-only answer... what flag reason should I pick? There is no flag option called link only answer... ok I'll pick 'other' and type link-only answer." Makes sense, but I later realized I was just creating extra work for the moderators for things that could be handled by myself and other users.

**The proper action is to flag link-only answers as "very low quality".** This will put the answer in the low quality review queue, where high rep users are given an option to delete posts with the reason "link-only answer". This is an almost certain way to get the answer deleted without involving diamond mods.

To the SO team: you might want to consider why there is no flagging option called "link-only answer". Because there exists a delete reason in the low quality review queue called "link-only answer". This is an inconsistency in the system, and it is particularly confusing to users who are used at doing low-quality post reviews and therefore expect to find a "link-only answer" option when they flag something.

Comment: *This is a link-only answer... what flag reason should I pick? There is no flag option called link only answer... ok I'll pick 'other' and type link-only answer.* that is exactly what happened to me in this case.

Comment: There seems to be a great deal of confusion as to which reason to use, perhaps we should add one for "Link only answer".

Comment: flagging very low quality is available only if answer has zero or lower score, positively scored answers _technically_ allow only NAA and Other kind flags. It also worth keeping in mind that per "Answer-Castle" guidance, NAA flag even for blatantly link-only answer is officially invalid in case if the question asks for links; that is "Q: gimme-linkz / A: here-linkz" means moderators are free to decline NAA (most LQ queue reviewers probably wouldn't care about such obscurities and recommend deletion anyway)

Comment: Perhaps redefining *Low Quality* option to include *Link only* answers will do, rather than introducing a new option... a *link only* answer is *Low Quality* in my opionion, unless the question specifically asks for links like @gnat mentioned. In that case, we should close the question itself rather than worrying about the answers since it is off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

You should have added the comment yourself, not delegated it to a moderator.

Moderators should only be involved when there is something you can't do by yourself (or in conjunction with other users).

In this case you should have:

1. Left the comment.
2. Down-voted the answer.
3. Edit the relevant information into the answer yourself.

If you do flag - don't use the "other" flag option just to say something like "link only answer". Use either "Not an answer" or "Very low quality". These flags are reviewed by other regular users who can also act on the answer.

If you think that the answer should have been converted into a comment (say) then state that in your flag. Moderators aren't mind readers.

Comment: Why not flag as "very low quality"?

Comment: @gunr2171 - why? That's what down-votes are for.

Comment: I'll repeat from [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272982) - _repeatedly just placing link only answer as a flag with no additional attempt to improve the answer isn't exactly the behavior we want. It could be possible that the "link answer" is the only answer to the question, it might actually be incredibly helpful - so losing this might not be making the internet better. First, we'd prefer commenting to the user to improve the answer, attempting to improve the answer via an edit or even posting a new answer with link details before any flags get sent to a moderator to delete/remove._

Comment: So do I need to flag any link-only answers?

Comment: @bluefeet Yet Shog made it very clear that [a post like this is not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381) and should be flagged accordingly.

Comment: @Servy Yet they used an "Other" flag for moderators to review. We don't need to be involved.  We shouldn't need to deal with these. That's what the VLQ queue is for.

Comment: @Bolu - Personally I'd like it if people **didn't** just flag link only answers, however, [there are others that think you should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381). However, if you do flag please make sure you have done at least one of the actions I list above and use the appropriate flag.

Comment: @bluefeet So if you wanted to say that the wrong flag reason was used, that'd be fine, but it's been made clear that this post *should* be flagged.

Comment: @Servy The flag was declined because a moderator didn't need to be involved in this.  I added a comment to the answer to give the user the chance to edit/improve the answer.

Comment: Whatever happened to converting answers to comments? This seems like a prime example of something that should be a comment, _not_ an answer. VLQ does not seem appropriate as their only option is leaving it be or deleting it outright. And just adding a comment and hoping the poster does anything to improve the answer evidently does not work.

Comment: @bluefeet Declinging the flag because he used the wrong type of flag is entirely appropriate, just make it clear that that's the reason the flag was declined.  He should have used NAA or possibly VLQ (they do the same thing at this point) rather than a custom flag.

Comment: I think, in this case, the answer should be converted to a comment at the best. that's why I didn't follow your listed steps..

Comment: @Bolu - in that case you should have included more detail in your flag.

Comment: OK, can I do it all over again? But shall I use NAA or use Other and say it's should be a comment?

Comment: @Servy ["wonder how long it will take for this _think-over_ to reach moderators who were conditioned for years to act opposite"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267567/link-only-answer-theres-a-tutorial-and-a-nicely-wrapped-class-available-here#comment71562_267569)

Comment: OK, [looks like the new trend is the opposite of this answer...](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/110323/discussion-on-question-by-glen-thomas-is-this-link-only-answer-ok).