# When are answers just linking to some one else Answer/Text Ok?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I ever thought answers that just contain links to content that is serving a answer aren't welcome on SO as answers. More they had to be a comment.

But when I reviewed those answers and flagged them as not a answer, as the should be a comment. I got the last 3 or 4 times declined. I even had a flagging lock because of flagging those answers.

So I kept in mind, those answers are ok, as long a answer of kind

> you should view this [link]

Is linking to good quality content.

Today (some days after my flagging lock expired) I was reviewing again and got a answer like this:

> This post gives you all the instructions and code to replicate the correlation chart you asked for.
>
> answered Oct 29 at 8:13
>   hvollmeier
>   44726

I inspected the link, which was containing a lot of content that was answering the question.

I thought "Well I personally don't like that kind of answer, as it just lets some one else look up stuff which the OP could also have been looking up, but ok. I kept in mind, thats not the pov of the community"

So I pressed "no action needed" and got:

> "STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This post was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful – passing over such posts hurts the ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above."

I feel kind of kidded...

So under which circumstances are link only answers ok and under which they aren't?

I mean its just a link, so not much additional information to judge about.

Comment: Audits aren't perfect, they just pick something that has a high amount of upvotes. You can go back and flag the post to take it out of rotation. Could you provide a link to the post?

Comment: No, as it is already deleted. And i just said no action needed. But after all, I'm confused now. Are link only answers in generell welcome on SO or aren't they. Is it a vise decission to flag them as not an answer or just tollerate them?

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your post the wrong way. That post should _absolutely_ be removed from the site. It does not give any useful information whatsoever. See the text that is in this post. Notice how there is no hyperlink. Does that text help you at all? It can't, and that's why link-only answers are forbidden. So yes, you failed the audit because you said "this is fine to stay on the site" instead of taking action to remove the content.

Comment: You have to be careful to differentiate between answers that are merely short and happen to contain a link, and answers that are only links to other posts which should be deleted. It is rare that a flag is declined if it is truly a link-only answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 "I got the last 3 or 4 times declined" -- this makes me think the problem is that [moderators in habit of declining flags on blatant link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275971/839601 "example") build wrong expectations about acceptable answer quality which further causes failing review audits

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> you should view this [link]

is not an ok answer. It doesn't contain any information whatsoever in the post itself. Even if that were a highly-upvoted, accepted answer I would convert it to a comment and ask the OP to flesh it out before reverting it back.

You can find the latest guidelines on link-only answers on the Meta SE post [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) I've seen several other Stack Overflow moderators and high-rep users cite that post, so I think it's what the majority of us are following.

Comment: as far as I can see, in this case automatic selection worked fine: "This post gives you all the instructions and code to replicate the correlation chart you asked for" is a sensible example of a known bad answer. I guess audit failure was caused by flag declines mentioned by OP, when moderators taught them that answers like in this audit are worth keeping

Comment: @gnat Ah, yes you're right about the review audit. I had it backwards. I removed the last paragraph from my answer.

Comment: This is fine when there are other answers to a question. I posted an answer by way of a link because it gave a complete answer to the question. But it was even removed. The question remained un answered. In my opinion this is not what Stack Overflow should be about. Further I find it way to easy to down mark answers without clear reasoning why the answer is bad.

Comment: @NigelFindlater the purpose of StackOverflow is to have the answers, not links to the answers - that's what Google is for. The convention we've settled on is that links can be submitted as a comment. If your answer wasn't converted to a comment then someone messed up.

Answer (score 5):

Just linking to another related answer is not good enough, in my opinion.

I have on occasion answered by referencing to another post, but I always try to do 3 things:

1. quote the most important pieces of the other answer
2. credit the author of the post I'm quoting from
3. try to explain why I feel the quote answers this new question

Most of the time the answer to the new question is not going to be exactly 100% the same as the original - in many cases that would point to a duplicate question which needs to be closed as such.

So there is greater value in taking the specific parts that relate, and adding an explanation specific to the new question.

---

Here is a case where I did just that:

- [Set Intents category programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612041/383414)

Answer (score -1):

**Never**

If the question B is answered by the answer to the question A, the correct action is to close B as the duplicate of A, not giving the 'answer' which is only a link.

Link only answers are never acceptable because they are useless until someone clicks on the link. Many people don't want to click on the external links because they don't trust the linked site, or it's not allowed in their organization, on for whatever reason. The linked site may move or be removed as well.

The link may be acceptable as the comment, but it is not acceptable as an answer.

Comment: Just because the answer of one question can also answer another question, doesn't mean it's a duplicate. I.e one course of action can be the solution to multiple problems. So then you can have internal link only answers. (I do agree with you that link only answers are not good and should add the important parts in the answer itself)