# Answer deleted with two hours' notice as being link-only, but the links are valid

Tags: support, link-only-answers, deletion

There was only a two hour window before the moderator decided to delete the answer. In the spirit of making the answer more informative, I have provided an update that addresses the specific part of the solution. But only two hours from moderator note to moderator deletion? That seems excessively fast.

[Tried to implement ELMAH - keep getting IIS HTTP 500.22 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847473/asp-net-tried-to-implement-elmah-keep-getting-iis-http-500-22-error/13847605?noredirect=1#comment49317152_13847605)

Comment: Nope.  Immediate deletion would have been acceptable.  Your edit appears good, I'd flag your answer and ask for it to be undeleted.

Answer (score 15):

While the links may be valid, the answer in it's original state was not the best. The timeline on this was the following:

- May 19th your answer was flagged as Not An Answer due to it containing pretty much [links without any context](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13847605/1)
- I was processing flags earlier today and came across this flag that has been sitting unhandled for several weeks because it was an accepted answer flagged as NAA
- I added a comment explaining that link only answers are discouraged and deleted the answer at the same time.

Since this has been sitting waiting to be handled by a moderator for weeks, I acted on it.  Once an answer has been edited into something besides the links, then you can flag it an request a moderator review it for undeletion.

After your edit to the answer, I've now undeleted it.

Comment: I should point out that this was exactly the behavior advocated by Shog9 in response to a similar situation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275980/19679 (ironically, where people got angry at bluefeet for *not* deleting such an answer).

Comment: @BradLarson I like to be controversial but I also learned from Shog's answer that I should be deleting it immediately instead of waiting around.

Comment: I don't have an issue with the deletion as such, but the time between notification and deletion and as to the post below there is rarely anything that needs to be done immediately unless spam or obscenity or otherwise inappropriate behavior is involved.

Comment: @MikeBeeler If we don't delete at that time, then we need to either leave the flag for another mod to handle it later or remember to go back and process it.  We have far too many flags to handle to leave stuff for later, especially when a user can edit an answer and then request undeletion.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the post *immediately* when a delete-worthy problem is found is the right thing to do.

"Deletion" in this case is soft deletion: the post is just hidden from users without [a certain privilege level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). The post can still be edited to work on the problem by anyone who can see it -- including the author -- while it's deleted, but whatever harm the post is causing is mitigated.