# What do we do with NAA answers which are accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer, not-an-answer

I wouldn't ask if there was clear guidance on this (which is what I'm looking for, and currently none of the answers do that). There are many answers on the topic (like this one on Meta.SE) but there still exists the different opinions about it. In an ideal world I'd like an 'official' instruction on it.

I was attempting to find an answer to another user's question when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886067/2422013) (10k+ only now that it's been deleted):

[image]

I [asked on the SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26156342#26156342) whether it is considered NAA as it is the accepted answer, so it obviously helped the OP. The answer I got back was that it *is* indeed NAA, but:

> Doubt you would get a mod to delete it.

- [Tiny Giant](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26156367#26156367)

I also got this:

> Yeah, I've never gotten a helpful flag on an accepted NaA. Every single time it has been declined.

- [Tiny Giant](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26156533#26156533)

Usually NAA answers link to some library (*which also makes the question off-topic most of the time*), but this one linked to a tutorial; this means that we can't simply take the code from the link and 'dump' it (with attribution) into the answer in-place of the link.

Which prompts the question: ***are NAA answers which are accepted eligible for deletion?***

A few things I thought could be done with this answer in particular:

- Replace the link to the [Internet Wayback Machine's archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301015530/http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/303235-visualizing-sound-from-the-microphone), to ensure the link is *always* valid, even if the original link rots away (unlikely seeing as it's `dreamincode.net`, but always a possibility)
- Delete the answer outright as NAA
- Dump the whole tutorial at the link in the answer

What is the proper way to deal with these answers which are NAA *and* also are the accepted answer?

Here are a few more 'accepted but NAA' answers:

- [Cycle2 Carousel - Pause continuous slider on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887371/2422013)
- [What is the right way to set up and running with code blocks and wxwidgets c++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798319/2422013)
- [Spring MVC + Spring REST + Spring Data JPA integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831409/2422013)

Comment: All but the last line of that question, including the title, reads like a recommendation question. I'm half and half on whether that last line would save it from closure as such, since the last line seems to actually be a question, and not a recommendation. Either way, if closure as a recommendation question is reasonable in this case... Deal with the question, then both of the poor answers will follow.

Comment: @Kendra I literally said exactly the same thing: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26156420#26156420.

Comment: I did flag that answer as not an answer but it was declined by a moderator for `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`.  I am not sure how the mods look at NAA flags but I don;t think that was right.

Comment: @NathanOliver Mine was declined too: http://puu.sh/kC2Ae/e9392f1189.png

Comment: Link to post is now broken for me, so I assume that the question itself got deleted.  My guess is we'll get an answer from someone very soon.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks, updated. I ended up custo-flagging the answer, asking why the NAA flag was declined & also linked this question there too.

Comment: @bob What? You raised a custom flag asking for a reason? If so, that's not a good idea. Flags are not for asking moderators to explain their actions. As to why your NAA flag was declined, if a moderator got to it after the question was deleted, there's nothing for them to do because the answer was deleted too. If the question was not deleted yet, and a moderator saw what the question was asking, then the moderator may have decided that the community could take care of it through votes to close and votes to delete (which is what happened).

Comment: Don't use a custom flag to ask mods questions- A lot, if not all, of them come to Meta on a decently regular basis. Your question here will be seen. Mods already get a ton of flags, you're just adding a noisy flag to it by doing that.

Comment: @Louis I know that... my custo-flag was more along the lines of 'this is NAA, I did flag it but it was declined. Is there a reason why it was declined?'.  http://puu.sh/kC46Y/64528b23d2.png

Comment: @Louis If the mod felt that the answer isn't NAA because the question is a reccomendation question then they used the wrong rejection message; they should have rejected it with the "insufficient evidence" text.

Comment: @Servy I agree. But then if the mod thought that, why didn't they straight-out instantly delete the question after  the first NAA flag (there were 3 or 4 NAA flags by different users (see the SOCVR))?

Comment: @bob The only valid reason I can think of for that rejection message is if Nathan used a custom mod flag, rather than a NAA flag, even though he said he flagged it as not an answer.  If he used a custom flag to say that the post is NAA then a mod rejecting it for using the wrong flag reason (which is how that rejection reason is used) would be entirely valid.

Comment: @Servy Point taken. In an ideal world I'd want feedback on how to proceed with these types of answer (accepted but NAA) in the future).

Comment: @bob Handle them exactly the same as you would a non-accepted answer.

Comment: @Servy A bit pointless if they're going to get declined, which is partially what this question's about.

Comment: @bob Indeed.  The question is *really* just about what to do when you disagree with the action a mod takes in response to a flag, not about how you should treat accepted non-answers versus non-accepted non-answers.

Comment: @bob If the answer is accepted, then that implies that it can't possibly qualify for NAA, since the guidelines for that reason are "doesn't attempt to answer the question", and the Question asker clearly demonstrated that the answer does in fact answer the question. It's at this point that you have to decide for yourself between theory and practice. Theory says it's NAA, but in practice, it is. I think it's reasonable to determine your answer to this dilemma in a case-by-case basis, even for moderators. tl;dr - do what you think is right.

Comment: @TylerH That makes the false assumption that the OP will only ever accept an answer that is actually an answer to the question.  Additionally, the site's minimum quality standards exist, and are there for good reason.  The fact that one user (the OP) doesn't care about them doesn't mean that everyone else should ignore them.

Comment: Guys, please carry on your discussion in [The Tavern](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks), the comment section isn't for discussion and I'm starting to get irritated of notifications of new comments here every 2 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @servy I did flag as NAA.

Comment: What is NAA?  Sorry for the newbie question...

Comment: @JonH Not an Answer (flag).

Comment: Maybe I'll edit it in as I am not really that much of a reviewer on the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was this not-an-answer flag declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275968/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)

Comment: @Fazovsky Uh, *no*. Why would you even think that this question is a duplicate of that? I'm asking for *guidelines*, I'm not looking for an answer for why *this specific answer's NAA flag was declined*.

Comment: Also: the reason I asked this question *in the first place* is because different moderators seem to have different opinions about NAA answers which are accepted. I wouldn't ask if there was clear guidance on it (which is what I'm looking for, and currently none of the answers do that). There are many answers on the topic (like [this one on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer)) but there still exists the different opinions about it. In an ideal world I'd like an 'official' instruction on it.

Comment: An important special case of this is when the link only answer is a **self-accept**, can you edit your question to talk about this case? I don't want to edit it myself because it's too drastic.

Comment: As @durron597 notes, self-accepted answers are a slightly different case. Two of the three examples you listed fall into this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I declined the flag on that answer and I'll try and explain my reasoning here. My decline was not because I liked the answer or wanted it to live on in any particular way, but because the underlying problem seemed to rest entirely in the question itself.

The question was in my view the root of the problem with **both** answers it attracted (although only one was flagged and only flagged as NAA which didn't really convey the scope of the problem), so when I viewed the NAA flag in the NAA queue the action I wanted to be taking was to close the question.

By the time I viewed the flag (in a tab popped out of the flag queue) the question had already been closed by the community, which is the preferred way of handling issues generally anyway. So at the point I had to make a call on what to do with it the one action I really wanted to take was on a different post and already handled by the community anyway, hence the decline with "*flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*" - there was nothing I wanted to do over and above the community actions on the question itself.

Comment: I don't hink this is fair to the flagger. If an answer is NAA by itself, it should be handled as such. Also an accepted NAA answer is misleading to readers, expecially with roomba not triggering for the question. It also could attract more upvotes which is also not a good signal to answerers who at least tried to stay within rules. Question and answer should be judged seperately in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

If the "answer" had not been accepted, I agree that it is link only and warrants NAA flagging.  But now consider what it means that such a non answer was accepted as the solution to the question.  It almost always means that **the question itself is off-topic**.  So instead of trying to convince a mod that an accepted answer is really not an answer, **close and/or delete the question instead**.  If the question is also unhelpful, it could also be deleted, which would take the answer with it.  These kinds of non-answers are why certain kinds of questions are considered off-topic; they attract answers like that.

There's also the unlikely possibility that the question is on-topic.  At this point, you'll just have to use your best judgement.  Options include editing the posts and voting.

Comment: I fail to see the logical steps that lead you to say that accepting a non-answer, by definition, means that the question is off topic.  It's entirely possible for a perfectly appropriate and on topic question to be asked, have a non-answer given, and then accepted because the OP lost their keys or whatever.  It could be a red flag to check if the question is off topic, but it's not something that strictly follows.

Comment: It's true that the OP can accept whatever they want, but I'd say a significant percentage of the time accepted non-answers are signs of a poor question.

Comment: There's a big difference between saying that accepted non answers means that the question is much more likely to be off topic and saying that accepting a non-answer strictly means that the question is off topic.

Comment: Just because the question has an answer "over there" doesn't mean it's off topic.

Comment: @KevinB that's true, but it's still a strong indicator of being either a recommendation question or too broad.

Comment: @servy, Original version indeed was questionable, with the edit "almost always" describes many of such question/answer pairs well.

Comment: to me, this answer is a perfect example of the issue discussed here

Comment: Big -1. The question should be judged *on its own merits* as the whether it's off topic. Just because the OP accepted a link answered doesn't mean it's off topic. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/1394393) is an excellent counter example. That answer was nearly link only to begin with and details were edited in long after the answer was accepted and highly upvoted. When this happens, it is at least equally likely that the link contains *useful content*, and in that case, the appropriate action would be to edit and *paraphrase the link content and leave the link as a citation*.

Comment: +1 for editing. If a link only answer is accepted, you can still edit it and provide some context, like the name of the site, the author of the solution, and a quick summary.  Hmm, yeah, a proper citation.

Answer (score -18):

I don't believe that calling something that provided a person with the information they need should be NAA.  Yes, it's far from ideal (link rot, and all the associated risks with having to click away from SO, etc).  However, if there's no truly correct answer and it solves the problem.  Well, I think the community is best served by leaving it be.  Should the link rot and someone runs across it in the future, flag it then.  If it rots and nobody finds out, well, it's not all that important then...  :-)

Keep in mind that first and foremost SO is about helping people.  Think carefully if what you're doing is mindlessly following rules or doing the right thing.

Comment: SO is about helping _people_. Plural. Not just the OP.

Comment: Saying "SO is about helping people" and not providing further qualification is misleading. SO is about building a compendium of quality questions and answers about programming. Yes, this does help people but the fact that SO is about questions and answers and the fact that it requires quality significantly affect the shape the help takes. There's good help and there's bad help.

Comment: I know that there's a goal of keeping quality high, but I just can't agree with the above arguments that result in useful information being removed.  It runs contrary to the primary goals of the site and is a result of being overly rule-bound.  Don't contribute to making the site so "stiff" that it's no longer useful.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: A link is not "information", let alone "useful information". Links are not answers, period.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's such a whacked out and ridiculous statement that it's apparent we will not be able to even have a constructive discussion here.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch how is that "whacked out"? If a link dies, how will the link provide any sort of useful information?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Plus1. *Helping the community is a result of helping individuals.* It is impossible that an act of help extended to an individual results in any harm to the community. The catch, of course, is in having incorrect idea of what *help* is. Giving away the solution to homeworks is not help. Guiding someone who has a very silly problem is surely help. As far as this link thing is concerned, it's an act of helping the OP. Strangely, people who didn't have the question that OP had, are discussing whether that question's answer is helpful. (No offence meant, dear friends :) )

Comment: That's right. If the answer answered the OP's question, then it is a good answer. That doesn't mean that the OP's question was a good one, or one that we encourage on this site. The solution to bad questions is not to get medieval on their answers, but to encourage the askers to ask better questions.