# Accepting an NAA answer - what should happen?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

<sub>I searched around on meta and found this relevant thread on the same topic: [What do we do with NAA answers which are accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307619/what-do-we-do-with-naa-answers-which-are-accepted) However, to the best of my ability, I've can say that the question in question is a legitimate, on-topic question and that it should not deleted.</sub>

---

Some time ago I answered a question here: [Python: Reading log if phase matches, print but stop after first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072762/python-reading-log-if-phase-matches-print-but-stop-after-first-match?noredirect=1#comment79108343_46072762).

Soon after posting my answer, another solution was posted which seemed like an obvious NAA:

> one way forward is remove key from dictionary after match and break
>   dictionary loop

It does not appear to actually answer the OP's question, which asks for assistance on how to fix their code which is not giving them the desired output, and also asks for how to improve it ("*I'm not sure if I'm going down the best route...*").

This is my reasoning. I believe that such questions cannot be justifiably answered without *at least* pointing out OP's current mistakes/shortcomings and *at least* showing them how to code a correct solution. However, the NAA in question does not provide a trace of code or explanation that would be considered useful to OP. This seemed suspicious to me. Furthermore, (and I understand this is not a criteria for flagging) but the accepted solution has some serious technical inaccuracies (as any python user would understand).

Acting on my instincts, I flagged the answer as NAA. Five hours later, the flag remained pending and OP has accepted the answer. Here are my questions (sorry if they're a lot):

- Should the answer have been flagged in the first place?
- Is this evidence of suspicious behaviour? Should a moderator take a closer look at these accounts?
- What happens to the flag now? Is it likely to age away since the answer has been accepted? If not, can it still possibly be removed through the review process?

Comment: Do note that usefulness is not something we flag on, it is something we vote on.

Comment: Five hours is not a particularly long time for a NAA flag to remain pending. And such flags do not age away anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray I see. Regarding my suspicions on the suspicious activity, must I file a new flag anyway or will you look into it?

Comment: Normally you would need to raise a second flag for suspicious activity. We don't routinely investigate that for NAA, and especially not if the community handles the NAA flag before a moderator ever sees it. I checked here, though, and don't see anything suspicious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Am I missing something here? Not much of a Python person, but it looks to me like he's *describing* (in prose) a code change that would resolve the asker's problem.

The asker has a bit of logic that does the following:

1. Construct a dictionary mapping log entries to phase descriptions
2. Read the log file line by line (end-to-start)
3. Iterate through the dictionary looking for a key that matches the current line
4. If found, print the mapped description and line.

Problem is, there are multiple log entries for the same phase, and he only wants it to print each phase once... So the answerer suggests,

> remove key from dictionary after match and break dictionary loop

Obviously if the key no longer exists in the dictionary then it'll never match a line in the log file again. So this would seem to be a sure-fire way of solving his immediate problem. Not to say it's a particularly *good* way to solve the problem - for starters, what's the point of having a dictionary if you're just gonna loop through it every time - but it probably *did* work, which means it *did* answer the question and thus is *not* NAA.

I declined your flag for that reason.

Comment: And now that you've met your flag quota for today, it's lunch-time!

Comment: It's "deal with moderator problems on another site and eat donuts" time, A.K.A. breakfast.

Answer (score 8):

No.  To the untrained eye, it still looks like an attempt to answer the question.  It shouldn't be flagged.  It'll likely get discarded/declined, since there's nothing a moderator can really do there.

What you should do *instead* is downvote the answer, and optionally leave a comment as to why it's poor.

I won't deny that it looks suspicious though...but I'm going to first give these folks the benefit of the doubt.  A custom moderator flag would be better suited for fishiness anyway, and you'll need to provide as much context and information as you can to them so they can make a clean determination.

Comment: Thank you for this. Should it have been flagged VLQ instead?

Comment: No, VLQ should be treated as equivalent to NAA. Both mean "this needs to be deleted". That answer didn't. It was relevant to the question and appeared to answer it. What you said in the question (*"I believe that such questions cannot be justifiably answered without at least pointing out OP's current mistakes/shortcomings and at least showing them how to code a correct solution."*) is your description of a *good* answer. These flags are for things that aren't even in the same universe as answers, not for answers you consider lousy or incomplete. You should still just downvote those. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the clarification (here, and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356213/accepting-an-naa-answer-what-should-happen/356214?noredirect=1#comment511620_356213)). Appreciate the help!